# Is there any default method in rxjs to call a function at a specific time of day?

Tags: javascript, rxjs

I am trying to find the solution but I didn't get that.

Using javascript I am able to achieve this. Please suggest is there any default function is there in rxjs to achieve the below requirement or not.

Requirement every day at 10:00 I want to make an API call and refresh the existing data.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

There's no special function to call a method at a specific time of day, but you can use a [`timer`](https://www.learnrxjs.io/learn-rxjs/operators/creation/timer) to count down to that time, then emit every 24 hours.

However, to protect against potential daylight savings time adjustments, it may be better to emit every hour and [`filter`](https://www.learnrxjs.io/learn-rxjs/operators/filtering/filter) for your desired time:

```js
const msPerHour = 1000 * 60 * 60;
const msUntilNextHour = msPerHour - new Date().getTime() % msPerHour;

// emit every hour at 0 minutes, 0 seconds
const onHour$ = timer(msUntilNextHour, msPerHour).pipe(
  map(() => new Date())
);

const dailyAt10am$ = onHour$.pipe(
  filter(now => now.getHours() === 10)
);

dailyAt10am$.subscribe(
  () => console.log("It's 10:00, let's do some work...")
);
```

Here's a [StackBlitz example](https://stackblitz.com/edit/so-67077793?file=index.ts).